# SetTimeout with standard counter

Tags: javascript

I want to create a alert "Hello" which will show up after 10sec. 
I used setTimeout and it working fine. 
Now i would like to do counter(timer) which will show 10, 9, 8,7 ... and then alert Hello.

```
function counter(){
    setTimeout(function(){alert("Hello")},10000);
}
```

Any ideas ? Don't want any css for that. Just a standard text counter. Is there something like that ?

Comment: No, there's nothing like that, you'd have to make it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to make one, setInterval would be a good choice for counter.

```
var time = 10, x = setInterval(function () {
  console.log(--time);
  if (time === 0) {
    alert("hello");
    clearInterval(x);
  }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple variant:

```
var count=10;

var counter=setInterval(timer, 1000);

function timer()
{
  count=count-1;
  if (count <= 0)
  {
     clearInterval(counter);
      alert("Finished!")
     return;
  }

 document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML=count + " secs"; // watch for spelling
}
```

Working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dczQ2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```
var count = 10; 
var timer = function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    alert(count);
    if(count == 0){
      //do something
    }
    else{
      count--;
      timer();
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

To run just:

```
timer();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `setInterval()` method calls a function or evaluates an expression at specified intervals (in milliseconds).

you can stop `evaluates` by `clearTimeout()` function.

Try the code

```
<p></p>

<script>
    var sObj = setInterval(function(){
     var obj = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
        if(obj.innerHTML == "0"){
            alert("hello");
            clearTimeout(sObj);
        }
        if(obj.innerHTML == ""){
          obj.innerHTML = 10;
        }else{
            var cur = parseInt(obj.innerHTML); 
          obj.innerHTML = cur - 1;
        }   
</script>
    }, 1000)
```